# Seeking guidance on data analysis techniques to estimate project LOE based on numeric counts of outputs produced

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-modeling, algorithms, estimation

I’m looking for some basic guidance on where to focus my research in support of some data analysis I’m looking to perform.

The problem space is identifying a methodology for estimating Level of Effort (LOE) for “projects” based on a collection of historical data points that specify counts for different types of digital asset produced with each project (where asset counts can be considered the output produced by a project)

- I have pulled data for approx 3000 projects (each a row) , and there is approx 40 different asset types (each a column) that can delivered with a project.
- Asset types include things like Product Images, Videos, 3D assets, Copy Strings etc etc
- Some projects may have a count well into the 1000s for some asset types, with counts spread across all 40 types. Others projects may only have single digit counts for only 1 or 2 asset types (and values of 0 for all other types)
- There are 5 to 8 core asset types (of the 40) that the workers consider to be generally the most indicative of LOE
- Of the 3000 projects, we have been provided actual LOE values from the business for approx 300 of them. The LOE values are sizes of either XS, S, M, L or XL
- The goal is to find a patten / relationship between asset counts and LOE using the 300 projects with provided LOEs, to subsequently apply to the other 2700 projects, and to create estimate LOEs for future projects based on the expected asset counts
- I’m technically proficient with Python, have decent experience using Pandas (although more for data manipulation than analysis). My ML proficiency is limited to rudimentary knowledge of statistics from some university courses completed 20 years ago

As you can see from these basic statistics, the counts are skewed, mostly a result of values of "0" being highly prevalent in the data set:
[image: Basic statistics on sample data]

Usually I would spend time slowly honing in on the right approach, but I’m under some time pressure to get to a solution. With that being the case I’m hoping someone can point me in the right direction as to where to start my research in the ML / Data Analysis space, with the above problem specifically in mind. I.e. what are some specific areas of interest or resources that I might find useful. Not looking for an answer per se, but some guidance on where to focus my research and learning to start making progress quickly.

PS. The areas I've initially started to look at is Data Scaling and/or standardization (to normalize the 40 odd data points) and then multiple regression.